# IE9 strips part of url

Tags: internet-explorer, stripping

Internet Explorer 9 is stripping (a large) part of a url - as entered into the address bar - why would it do this?

The complete url is (domain has been disguised):
http://sec.internalhostname.com/mailings/survey/response/post1.php?u=1036&fm=371&c=885830&ml=7646837&ah=sf&sfid=00QE000000K0THJMA3&sftp=Lead&w=field&qn=XX_Current_NSF_Provider__c&fn=Checks+are+guaranteed&ft=2&fsft=picklistvalue

When entered, IE changes this to:
http://sec.internalhostname.com/mailings/survey/response/

and the rest of it seems to have disappeared!
ie.
post1.php?u=1036&fm=371&c=885830&ml=7646837&ah=sf&sfid=00QE000000K0THJMA3&sftp=Lead&w=field&qn=XX_Current_NSF_Provider__c&fn=Checks+are+guaranteed&ft=2&fsft=picklistvalue

Needless to say, it does not find the page and shows a 'Not Found' error.

Has anyone experienced this before? It is very puzzling.

Colin G

Comment: Are you doing this as a POST?

Comment: The link is down btw. I can't reproduce an issue like this. Which IE version do you use?

Comment: Doesn't happen at my box